# Forms and Objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I need help on how to properly construct this. My goal is that I can type a person's name and subject on the form and have it show the student's grade for that subject.  I don't know how to approach this.  As you can see, I don't know how to set this up.  Any suggestions on how to attack this?

**HTML Code**

```
    <form name="reportcard">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Enter Student's name here:</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Student Name:</td>
                <td id="student"><input type="text" name="student1"></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject</td>
                <td id="subject"><input type="text" name="subject1"></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="callParents()"></td>
            </tr>

        <p id="hello"></p>

    </form>

</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Student (name, art, science, english, spanish, shop, socialScience, gym) {
  this.aname = name;
  this.math = art;
  this.science = science;
  this.english = english;
  this.spanish = spanish;
  this.shop = shop;
  this.socialScience = socialScience;
  this.gym = gym;
  }

var johnSmith = new Student ("John Smith", "B", "A", "A", "F", "A", "B", "A");

var janeSmith = new Student ("Jane Smith", "A", "B", "C", "A", "F" , "C", "A");

var jackSmith = new Student;
  jackSmith.aname = "Jack Smith";
  jackSmith.math = "A";
  jackSmith.shop = "A";

function callParents () {
  if (jackSmith.shop === "F") {
  console.log("Call Parents!!!");
     } else {
    console.log("Student is doing fine in school");  
  }
```

Comment: JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7ap2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...I have made a few changes to both your html as well as JavaScript code

In html, you don't need the `td` to have an id, instead I have put the `Id` for the input elements.
Here is modified html code:

```
    <body>

    <form name="reportcard">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Student's name here:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Student Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="student" type="text" name="student1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subject</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject1">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="callParents();">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <p id="hello"></p>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

In the JavaScript code, instead of keeping all student objects separate, I have made them into a single collection of student list. So it would be easier to loop. And also added the extra code to check for the Student name and to check grade.

Here is the modified JavaScript code:

```
    function Student(name, art, science, english, spanish, shop, socialScience, gym) {
    this.aname = name;
    this.math = art;
    this.science = science;
    this.english = english;
    this.spanish = spanish;
    this.shop = shop;
    this.socialScience = socialScience;
    this.gym = gym;
}

var johnSmith = new Student("John Smith", "B", "A", "A", "F", "A", "B", "A");

var janeSmith = new Student("Jane Smith", "A", "B", "C", "A", "F", "C", "A");

var jackSmith = new Student();
jackSmith.aname = "Jack Smith";
jackSmith.math = "A";
jackSmith.shop = "A";


var studentList = [];
studentList.push(johnSmith);
studentList.push(janeSmith);
studentList.push(jackSmith);





function callParents() {

    var name = document.getElementById('student').value;

    var sub = document.getElementById('subject').value;

    for (var i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
        if (studentList[i].aname == name) {
            if (studentList[i][sub] == 'F') {
                console.log("Call Parents!!!");
            } else {
                console.log("Student is doing fine in school");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k7ap2/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You should have an object with student entries, acting as a map between student name and grades. Then you add an event listener to the button and call the function which edits the output.

This is how it could look like:

```
var students = {};
students["John Smith"] = new Student ("John Smith", "B", "A", "A", "F", "A", "B", "A");
students["Jane Smith"] = new Student ("Jane Smith", "A", "B", "C", "A", "F" , "C", "A");
students[jackSmith.aname] = jackSmith;

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', callParents);

var student = document.getElementById('student1');
var subject = document.getElementById('subject1');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function callParents() {
    if (subject.value && student.value) {       
        var grade = students[student.value][subject.value];
        output.innerHTML = grade === 'F' ? 'Call parents!' : grade;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7ap2/6/)